# Generating a PDF from images

Tags: shell, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a serie of ten images. I would like to have them stretched to fit 5in squares centered in a single A4 PDF, one image per page.

I would need something working on Mac (in case of some local command line subtleties).

Comment: I use `pdfimages` command from poppler-utils package in debian.

Comment: Could you expand to show what you've tried so far ? You've tagged it with `imagemagick`, have you tried the `convert` utility that comes with it, e.g. `convert image01.jpg image02.jpg photo.jpg -compress jpeg -quality 75 test.pdf`

Comment: @steve I know that imagemagick could be used for that. I didn't tried much to be honest, as I don't know how to center or enforce the page size itself. Your command is putting all images in a PDF document but no size is given to them and the document is not A4

Comment: @PersianGulf `pdfimages` extracts raster images from PDF files.  The OP wants the converse, to construct a PDF from a set of images.

Comment: Try having a play with ImageMagick's convert utility and its `-page A4`, `-gravity center` options.  e.g. `convert -page A4 image01.jpg image02.jpg image03.jpg -gravity center -format pdf test.pdf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ImageMagick, at 300 DPI:

```
convert -page 2480x3508 -extent 2480x3508 -density 300 -gravity Center *.png out.pdf
```

The "magic" numbers `2480x3508` are the dimensions in pixels of an A4 page at 300 DPI.  See [here](http://www.papersizes.org/a-sizes-in-pixels.htm) for the dimensions at other resolutions if you need something different than 300 DPI and you can't be bothered to do the scaling yourself.  Add `-background black` to get the images on black.

Comment: +1 for a nice ImageMagic solution that works without GUIs and even works on a RaspberryPi

Comment: i love that you care about explaining the "magic number". Thanks for that, this is exactly what I am looking for (and purely command line based), could you please add a conversion of all images to the right resolution before I accept?

Comment: @AsTeR What you want to do for PDF is adapt the resolution to the size of the images, rather than scale the images to a made-up resolution. _shrug_

Comment: I need them to take a limited space on the page, I should adjust with "extent"?

Answer (score 4):

## ◉ Using Terminal Emulator + Preview Application

Follow the steps below:

### ○ Change hight and width to 5"x5" and PDF format

The built-in command you have on MacOS X for scriptable image processing, is called `sips` (BSD Command).

**5"x5" is equal to 300x300 pixels.**

Let's pretend we have **thousands** of `*.jpg` files in our current directory, and We want them all to be converted to 5"x5" `*.pdf` files and be saved in `~/Downloads/Test` directory, all we should do is:

```
$ for i in *.jpg; do sips -s format pdf -p 300 300 $i --out ~/Downloads/Test/$i.pdf; done
```

Done! Now it's Preview's turn ↴

### ○ Center 5"x5" *.pdf files in a single A4 PDF

Go to `~/Downloads/Test`, use **⌘A** to select all files, now Open them With Preview, then use **⌘P**, then change the Paper Size to A4, Check the Scale instead of Scale to Fit option, and use use 100% for scale. Now Save it as a new PDF file.

[image]

Voila! Here is your desired PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's not pure command line but that is cool!